# implement Pseudocode code without return in c#

Tags: c#, return, winapp

how can i implement this Pseudocode without return in c#(because i want to use it in button event handler)?thanks

**edited:**

```
 large_int example(large_int u,large_int v)

  {
     .
     .       
     .////some codes
     .
        x=u divide 10^2;
        w=v divide 10^2;
 return example(x,w)///it means when example(x,w) returns, x replace with u and w replace with v
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "without return" ? What do you want to do with the result ?

Comment: return example(x,w) means when example(x,w) returns, x replace with u and w replace with v – arash 8 hours ago i want to do this work without using return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the method void, perform the same logic, and update something on your UI based on the result of the operation.

Not sure if you mean for ASP.NET, but if you do...

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" Text="Do Stuff" runat="server" OnClick="My_Event_Method" />

protected void My_Event_Method(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    example(someArg, someArg2);
}

private void example(int u, int v)
{
    // perform logic here and update your UI
}
```

Comment: thanks,but i want for c# winapp

Comment: @arash: the same idea is still applicable.

Comment: think i didnt say my question clearly,please see my edited question,x and w are the values that used in example() and they arent new,with your code i cant use x and w

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is that a recursive method then?

Comment: yes,the value in x and w return instead of u and v

Comment: it means when example(x,w) returns, x replace with u and w replace with v

Answer (score 3):

You could pass in a variable that has to be set within the method.

[MSDN on C# out keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: think i didnt say my question clearly,please see my edited question,x and w are the values that used in example() and they arent new,with your code i cant use x and w

Comment: return example(x,w) means when example(x,w) returns, x replace with u and w replace with v